# express post request body shows up as empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

server code

```
const express = require('express');
const app =  express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:true }));

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

client code

```
const data = {idk:'stuff',idk2:'otherstuff'};

fetch('http://localhost:4000', {
    method:'POST',
    headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    mode:'no-cors',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

terminal shows: {}
tried pretty much everything so help would be very much appreciated thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `mode: 'no-cors'` which tells `fetch` to silently ignore anything which requires CORS permission.

Setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` requires CORS permission so your request is sent with `Content-Type: text/plain` instead.

This doesn't trigger the JSON body parser.

- **Don't** use `mode: 'no-cors'`.
- **Do** configure your server to [give permission using CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

Comment: i tried setting the header of the response to (res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");) 
but it only seemed to work with get requests

Comment: @NatiReitblat — Sending a JSON request requires a preflight, see the link in this answer about configuring Express to handle thouse.